# Table-type bullets

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize

How does one organize bullets in an `array` instead of just as a `list`? For example, regular bullets would look like so:

- roses are red
- violets are blue
- I lost the game
- so did you

What I am hoping for is something like this which I have shabbily tried to demonstrate using very low-tech techniques (I wonder what):

[image]

Comment: Package `tasks`, for example or `paralist`

Comment: @EChen: That's a SO site, not on TeX.SX ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a `tasks` package - version (well, misusing the package a little bit ;-)

For a two column setup, say `\begin{tasks}(2)`  (Note the parentheses!)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tasks}
\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}[counter-format={-}](2)
  \task roses are read
  \task violets are blue
  \task I lost the game 
  \task so did you
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]